# Set date for countdown timer

Tags: javascript, html, countdown

I need to set countdown timer on my website. I have a deadline date and now the timer needs to countdown till that date.

My current code is:

```
  <script>
                    function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
              var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
              var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
              var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
              var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
              var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
              return {
                'total': t,
                'days': days,
                'hours': hours,
                'minutes': minutes,
                'seconds': seconds
              };
            }

            function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
              var clock = document.getElementById(id);
              var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
              var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
              var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
              var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

              function updateClock() {
                var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

                daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
                hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
                minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
                secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

                if (t.total <= 0) {
                  clearInterval(timeinterval);
                }
              }

              updateClock();
              var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
            }

            var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
            initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
        </script>
```

With this code, every time I visit my website, the timer starts to countdown from "15days".

Comment: `Date.parse(new Date())` is the overly complicated version of `new Date().getTime()`. And it starts from "15days" because `deadline` is (_"now"_ + 15 days).

Comment: Which deadline did you have in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes it’s necessary to preserve the state of the clock for more than just the current page. For example, if we wanted a ten minute countdown across the site, we wouldn’t want the clock to reset every time the user goes to a different page or every time the user refreshes the page they are on.

One solution is to save the clock’s end time in a cookie. That way, navigating to a new page won’t reset the end time to ten minutes from now.

Here’s the logic:

1. If a deadline was recorded in a cookie, use that deadline.
2. If the cookie isn’t present, set a new deadline and store it in a cookie.

To implement this, replace the `deadline` variable with the following:

```
// if there's a cookie with the name myClock, use that value as the deadline
if(document.cookie && document.cookie.match('myClock')){
  // get deadline value from cookie
  var deadline = document.cookie.match(/(^|;)myClock=([^;]+)/)[2];
}

// otherwise, set a deadline 10 minutes from now and 
// save it in a cookie with that name
else{
  // create deadline 10 minutes from now
  var timeInMinutes = 10;
  var currentTime = Date.parse(new Date());
  var deadline = new Date(currentTime + timeInMinutes*60*1000);

  // store deadline in cookie for future reference
  document.cookie = 'myClock=' + deadline + '; path=/; domain=.yourdomain.com';
}
```

EDITED:

Also you can remove your code

```
var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

And replace with this line. You will create date for countdown

```
var deadline = 'December 31 2018 23:59:59 GMT+0200';
```

This is full code:

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
                
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = 'December 31 2018 23:59:59 GMT+0200';
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

```css
body{
 text-align: center;
 background: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

#clockdiv{
 font-family: sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline-block;
 font-weight: 100;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 30px;
}

#clockdiv > div{
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: #a9a9a9;
 display: inline-block;
}

#clockdiv div > span{
 padding: 15px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: #585858;
 display: inline-block;
}

.smalltext{
 padding-top: 5px;
 font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="clockdiv">
  <div>
    <span class="days"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="hours"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="minutes"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="seconds"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
  </div>
</div>
```